# Building conditional mongoose query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've been trying to get this query working and am extremely frustrated.

I'm trying to search against either the email or username with the email not matching the one passed. I'm passing `searchstr` and email to the function.

I get as far as step 1 and then it gives me undefined error. It goes away when i comment everything except the `var query = user.find()`.

I've also tried `user.find({email:searchstr});` to make sure its not the query but that works.

What am I doing wrong?

```
var friendlist = { friendslist: []};

var query = user.find();
query.or([{ email: searchstr }, { username: searchstr }]);
//query.where(email);
//query.ne(email);

query.exec( function (err,users) {
    if(err != null) {console.log(err); callback({'res': false});}
    console.log('step1')
    users.forEach( function (err,userss) {
        if(err != null) {console.log(err); callback({'res': false});}
        console.log('step2')
        friendlist.friendslist.push({
                    "profileURLImage" : userss.profile_pic_server,
                    "currentStatus" : userss.profile_status,
                    "userName" : userss.username,
                    "email" : userss.email,
                    "online_status" : userss.online_status
                });
    });
});
```

Comment: What exactly is not working for you? The query condition will try to match "email" and if that returns false will then try to match "username".

Comment: It gives me a undefined error, but it works the second I comment out the or function.

Comment: Perhaps show a sample document to make your question more clear to others.

Comment: Are you saying `query.or` is failing? I'd suggest you use the debugger to step into the code of Mongoose to get more details.

Comment: What's `user` in the code?

Comment: user is the one of the mongoose models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get the query to work the way I wanted it to but I did get a workaround for it, if anyone can give a better answer that works than I'll select it as the answer.

main mistake I made was in the forEach as there isn't an err variable I guess.

```
var friendlist = { friendslist: []};

var query = user.find();
query.or([{ email: searchstr }, { username: searchstr }]);
//query.where(email);
//query.ne(email);

query.exec( function (err,users) {
    if(err != null) { console.log('error'); console.log(err); callback({'res':false});}
    users.forEach( function (userss) {
        if(userss.email != email) {
            friendlist.friendslist.push({
                    "profileURLImage" : userss.profile_pic_server,
                    "currentStatus" : userss.profile_status,
                    "userName" : userss.username,
                    "email" : userss.email,
                    "online_status" : userss.online_status
                });
        }
    });
    callback({'friends': friendlist.friendslist, 'res':true});
});
```